# A column definition list is required for functions returning "record" with dblink in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I have the following query in a function in Postgres:

```
SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(row_to_json(T)))
INTO _units
FROM (
    SELECT id, code, name, region::smallint
    FROM "myorg.lib.schema".units
    WHERE region::smallint =region
) T;
```

Now I need to use `DBLink` here as the above schema is in a different instance. So I am using the following:

```
SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(row_to_json(T)))
INTO _units
FROM dblink(
    db_string,'SELECT id, code, name, region::smallint
    FROM "myorg.lib.schema".units
    WHERE region::smallint ='|| region
) T
```

When executing the function, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=database_name port=1234 host=1.2.3.4
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15
```

actually, I am using DBLink for the first time and it will be very much helpful if someone can point out what is the error here and how to fix this. Thanks !!

Comment: Please start with the documentation for that feature.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you have to provide a column definition list, otherwise the SELECT does not know how to handle the return values.

In your example:

```
SELECT (...)
INTO (...)
FROM dblink(
    db_string,'SELECT id, code, name, region::smallint
    FROM (...)
    WHERE (...)'
) T(id integer, code text, name text, region smallint)
```

(replace types by actual types)

For exact syntax and more examples refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/contrib-dblink-function.html